# SharePoint 2007 web application/website not showing up [white screen]

Tags: 2007, web, ssl, certificate

I updated few dlls related to my timer job on SharePoint development box and my web application stopped working. Now if I say web application stopped working then I mean when I try to go to  web address

"usa999.asdkjas.com" nothing comes up even when try to go to settings by putting "_layouts/settings.aspx" it takes me no where shows a blank page, I looked into ULS log and nothing comes up.

just to mention it was working earlier, we got 2 websites with different IP address and certificates and they both are enabled with SSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone made unknown changes to web.config which was later on solved by putting in backup of web.config for same web application, however I guess it was something to do with HttpRedirectModule

Hope it helps if someone else get same issue :)